# How to loop over a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like:

```
mylist = [{2: 1451989654}, {3: 1435222955}, {4: 1346726067}, {53: 1451887667}, {723: 1445763454}]
```

I'd like to do something like

```
for key, val in mylist:
   print key 
   print val
```

How best can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mylist` is a list so you would need to loop through the list first:

```
for dct in mylist:
    for key, val in dct.items():
        print key
        print val
```

Note: you need `dict.items()` (or `.iteritems()`) to get both key and value

Comment: It should be ``print val`` instead of ``print value`` otherwise an Error is raised. And ``.items()`` doesn't work with python2 or?

Comment: What's the difference between `.items()` and `.iteritems()` ?

Comment: @Jand ``iteritems`` returns a generator and ``items`` returns a copy.

Comment: @MSeifert which one is faster?

Comment: ``iteritems`` consumes less memory, don't know if they are different in speed

Comment: @MSeifert why do you say `.items()` doesn't work for Py2?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have duplicate keys in your dictionaries why do you save it inside a list?

You can just save everything in one dictionary (or convert it later) so it's much easier to access the data (including printing):

```
mylist = [{2: 1451989654}, {3: 1435222955}, {4: 1346726067}, {53: 1451887667}, {723: 1445763454}]
mydict = {k:d[k] for d in mylist for k in d} # Convert the list to one dictionary
for k in mydict:
    print k, mydict[k]
```

and this prints:

```
2 1451989654
3 1435222955
4 1346726067
53 1451887667
723 1445763454
```

notice however that if you want your data ordered you might need to default to [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and replace the conversion with:

```
mydict = OrderedDict([(k, d[k]) for d in mylist for k in d])
```

Comment: This makes sence. But my clumsy list of dicts is the outcome of a rather long chain of stunts, on which I have little influence :)